# Convex optimization in a domain

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Considering the domain
$$S_1=\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^2\ni0\le x_1\le1,|x_2|\le\frac{x_1}2\}$$

Is $S_1$ convex?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried hessian, but that wouldn't really make much sense in this question, because we aren't dealing with matrices.

Comment: Please re-edit your question with your attempts, including the one you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider this image of this set, and the Wikipedia  definition of a [Convex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set).

[image]

Comment: so I'm assuming since, our shape has less than 180 degrees we can conclude that our function is convex?

Comment: the *set is convex because we can pick any two points in the set and if we drew a line between those two points, all the points on that line are contained in the set